# Angular2 (rc.6) JSON object keys not being accessed

Tags: json, angular, angular2-observables

I'm starting my first Angular2 (rc.6) project.
I have a JSON object successfully being sent to a component but I cannot access its keys values in the template.

SERVICE (excerpt):

```
@Injectable()
export class SongService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getSong(id: number): Promise<Song> {
    let url = '/maxapirest/v1/maxmusic/song/'+id
    console.log(url)
    return this.http
      .get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.json());
          return response.json();
      } )
  }
```

COMPONENT (excerpt):

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'my-song-reading',
  templateUrl: STATIC_URL+'song-reading.component.html',
  providers: [ SongService ],
})  

export class SongReadingComponent implements OnInit {
  song: Promise<Song>;
  constructor(
    private songService: SongService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
        let id = +params['id'];

        this.song = this.songService.getSong(id)
      }
    });

  }
```

~

TEMPLATE (excerpt):

```
<div *ngIf="song">
    {{ song | async | json }}<br/><br/><br/>
    {{ song.title | async}}
    {{ song.image | async }}
    {{ song.id | async}}
</div>
```

The issue I cannot figure out is that {{ song | json }} correctly outputs a JSON object:
{ "id": 71, "title": "It Don't Mean A Thing" ... }
And no error is thrown.
But the other var keys are not rendered whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you get anything ?check with `console.log(this.song)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.then(...)` and then assign the value there:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
        let id = +params['id'];

        this.songService.getSong(id)
        .then(json => {
          this.song = json;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks! I wasn't taking in account the Promise cycle... Of course I also had to change song: Promise<Song>; to song: {};